# How to fix this error message : Trying to get property of non-object Line 214

Tags: codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/index.php
>
> Line Number: 214
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci2\application\site\views\index.php
>   Line: 214 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci2\application\site\controllers\Cspages.php
>   Line: 32 Function: view
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci2\index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once

---

**views/index.php**

**Line 214:**

```
 <?php foreach($pic as $pic_item): ?> 
     <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets1/images/slider/'.$pic->pic_item
        );?>">
```

**controllers/Cspages.php**

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->helper('url');

  $this->load->model('gallery_model');

  // slider
  $pic_unique_id = 18;

  $data['pic'] = $this->gallery_model->get_picture($pic_unique_id);

  $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

**models/Gallery_model.php**

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model {
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }

  public function get_picture($pic_unique_id)
  {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('galleries_pictures', array('picture_unique_id' => $pic_unique_id));
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

How to fix this error message, any clue?  (Line 214)

Comment: seems there is no error in your code check your environment .. its may be in your PC

Answer (score 0):

Return `$query->row()` instead of `$query->result()` in model.

```
 public function get_picture($pic_unique_id)
  {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('galleries_pictures', array('picture_unique_id' => $pic_unique_id));
    return $query->row();
  }
```

> `row()` method returns the first matched row.If you use `result()` you need to use `foreach` loop in view.

For more see here [Codeigniter Results Formats](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this  $this->load->database();

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Your missing table name

```
public function get_picture($pic_unique_id) {
  $query = $this->db->get_where('tablename', array('picture_unique_id' => $pic_unique_id));
 return $query->result();
}
```

Or Try

```
public function get_picture($pic_unique_id) {
   $this->db->where('picture_unique_id', $pic_unique_id);
   $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
   return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use

```
 <?php foreach($pic as $pic_item): ?> 
     <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets1/images/slider/'.$pic->pic_item
  );?>">
```

$pic is array

try

```
 $pic_item->column_from_gallery_model;
```